# Send SMS using POST request from Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have an SMS API from textlocal which I want to use to send SMS using Cloud function when a new Document is created in Firestore Collection.
Collection name: Booking SMS. It will have a document created with fields 'number', 'name' & 'service'. Now SMY API need few parameters to send SMS.

API URL: 'https://api.textlocal.in/send/'

1. Apikey
2. Sender
3. Message. Message will be constructed as **'Hi, 'name' your booking of 'service' is confirmed.**

Name, service & number will be from Firestone document and apikey and sender will be coded in cloudfunction code.
Now I want to create cloudfunction trigger which will send sms when document is created. Below is incomplete code I tried please help me to complete it.

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
   const admin = require("firebase-admin");
 const axios = require("axios");

 admin.initializeApp()


 exports.sendSMS = functions.firestore
.document('BookingSMS/{BookingSMSId}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {

    const smsOptions = axios.create( {
        baseURL: "https://api.textlocal.in/",
        params: {
            apiKey: "xQ1Fvg7uv14NaAEQHl2D", //Text local api key
            sender: "ASDASD",
            test: "true",
            number: snap.data().phone,
            service: snap.data().service,
            message: `Hi, Your Booking for ${snap.data().service} is 
 Confirmed. Thank You.`
         }


    });
    smsOptions.post("/send");

});
```

I also want to add +91 before number. and construct message using name and service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://www.textlocal.in/free-developer-sms-api/), there is no direct support for node.js. You should be able to use their get request though. (Hope you're familiar with async/await)
Try:

```
async function bookSMS(user) {
        // 5. Send booking SMS to users
        const smsoption = {
                apikey: 'asasasasasasasasas',
        sender: 'DDDDDD'
                to: '${user.phone}',
                message: 'Welcome!',

        }
        // 6. Process the sending of this SMS
        await fetch(`https://api.textlocal.in/send/?apikey=${apiKey}&numbers=${user.phone}&message=Welcome!&sender=DDDDDD`)
}
```

**You must enable billing to access external APIs in firebase**

Comment: Hi, I have written new code from referring to different sources. I don't know javascript please can you give me complete code. I could try and test But it need to be deployed and Improper code can result in huge billing from google. If you can Please give me complete code. Thanks.

Comment: I request you to take a javascript tutorial if you want to continue with Firebase. Firebase cloud functions are solely written in Node.js and if you do not know how to write code in javascript, I'd also suggest you to look for other alternatives which suit your requirement.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I only needed this for SMS function So I thought I will do it with the help.

Comment: I have basically copied the code from your old method. Please refer to that code (before edit)

Comment: I got it working. But I hardly made 107 invocations and I was charged for CPU seconds and Gb seconds. I was charged only few paise. But I should get free seconds as mentioned. rest show within free tier limit. my function takes about 3000miliseconds it it normal for such request.

Comment: You have to investigate what time is taken by textlocal. If their api is taking long to respond, it is the issue of textlocal and not firebase. Save the timestamp before the request is sent, save the timestamp after the response is received and the difference is the time taken for that request. If the request is taking long time, contact textlocal. If you want another alternative, I have used ```2factor.in``` before. It works good with cloud functions.

Comment: Ok Thanks. Do you have any idea why I am getting billed for CPU and GB seconds in free tier. I am sure I didn't completed quota. I just made about 107 invocation. Do the bill and give discount at the end.

Comment: Have a look under the billing section of your firebase project. They will give the breakdown of which part of your project is causing the charges.